# Is there a CSS selector matching processing instructions?

Tags: html, css, xml, processing-instruction

I'm having a HTML document that contains processing instructions and should be styled using CSS. I didn't find any way to refer to the processing instructions from CSS. Is this possible?

```
<div>
  Hello World
  <?pi1 ?>
  Test
  <?pi2 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a style to every PI element you are adding or just for one PI element in particular ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Browsers will treat them as [bogus comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/syntax.html#bogus-comment-state), so in the DOM they will be *comment* nodes. CSS selectors match *element* nodes, so the processing instructions are not referable.

Comment: So there is also no fast way to get all processing instructions from the document using javascript? I don't consider looping through the whole DOM tree as fast ;-) Because if CSS would work I could have used querySelectorAll.

Comment: Processing instruction nodes can be inserted into the DOM dynamically, though.

Comment: @user3840170 - Indeed. And also via the HTML5's XML syntax parser. But the question was about HTML, not DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38760369/3840170) is correct in pointing out that parsing HTML will never generate processing-instruction nodes.  This is covered (as of April 2023) by [HTML LS §13.2.5.6](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tag-open-state).  However, such nodes can still be constructed and inserted into the DOM tree dynamically at runtime, using [`createProcessingInstruction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createProcessingInstruction) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).  They will even appear in `.innerHTML` of parent nodes, even though they won’t round-trip losslessly through HTML parsing.  They remain fully supported in XML DOM.

That said, processing instruction nodes, like comment nodes, will not participate in styling, even when inserted dynamically.  As such, there are no CSS selectors that can pick them, not even in `querySelectorAll`.  Processing instruction nodes can be picked by [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/) expressions, however, as supported by [`evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) and [`createExpression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createExpression):

```js
const xpath = function* (expr, node = document) {
    const result = document.evaluate(expr, node);

    for (;;) {
        const item = result.iterateNext();
        if (item === null)
            break;
        yield item;
    }
};

document.body.appendChild(
    document.createProcessingInstruction('foo', '123'));
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createProcessingInstruction('bar', '456'));
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createProcessingInstruction('quux', '789'));
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createProcessingInstruction('bar', '31337'));

for (const piNode of xpath('.//processing-instruction("bar")')) {
    console.log(`PI node: target=${piNode.target} data=${piNode.data}`);
}
```

An unfortunate complication here: as of April 2023, `evaluate` does not work on `DocumentFragment` nodes in major browsers (Firefox ESR 102 and Chromium 111).  Or rather, a `DocumentFragment` cannot be used as a context node, even though it can be selected by queries like `..` or `/`.  Attempts will generate a `DOMException`.  Adjust accordingly.